# Formatting a horizontal list of lists, how to fix the height of dynamic html

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a Site Map type of menu to sit at the bottom of the page, giving quick access to the first two levels of the site structure. However I'm having trouble formatting the lists so they neatly display when wrapped.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to get to:
[image: Desired footer menu layout]

However, what I end up with looks like this:
[image: Badly formatted list]

Here's the code simplified to show the problem, and a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PV8Bq/)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #footer-menu { 
            float:left; 
            background:#454545; 
            color:#FFFFFF; 
            width:850px;
            margin:50px auto 0 auto; 
            padding:10px 10px 2px 10px; 
            display:inline;
        }
        #footer-menu ul { 
            padding:0; 
            list-style-type:none; 
            left:auto; 
            overflow: auto; 
        }
        #footer-menu li { 
            margin:0 20px 5px 0; 
            padding-left:6px; 
            list-style-type:none; 
            float:left; 
            display:inline; 
            background:none; 
            position:relative; 
            font-family:Arial; 
            font-weight:bold; 
            border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
        }
        #footer-menu ul li ul {
            margin:5px 0 5px 0;
        }
        #footer-menu ul ul li {
            float:none; 
            padding:0; 
            margin:0 0 2px 0; 
            font-weight:normal; 
            display:block; 
            width:auto; 
            border:0;
        }
        #footer-menu a { 
            text-decoration: none; 
            color: white;
        }
        #footer-menu a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline; 
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="footer-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">List 1 Title is quite looooong</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">List 2 Short title</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">List 3 Title of average length</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">List 3 Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 3 Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 3 Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">List 4 with no sub items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List 5 Should wrap under list 1</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The items in the list come from the site map XML file via a script to generate the HTML, the list will change as pages are added to the site, so I'm looking for a solution which will not require me to manually adjust the height of the lists in order for it to format correctly.

Is it possible, using CSS, to fix the height of the entire row of lists so any wrapped list starts on the left hand side of the new row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PV8Bq/3/)

Works perfect in Firefox.

Changed

```
#footer-menu li {
    margin:0 20px 5px 0;
    padding-left:6px;
    list-style-type:none;
    /*float:left;
      display:inline;
    */
    /*Added this */ 
    display:inline-table;

    background:none;
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like all the lists to begin at the top of the div. Your solution setting the vertical alignment to bottom creates space at the top which looks a bit odd.

Comment: @Tony my solution does not have any vertical alignment to bottom. Please check again.

Comment: Sorry, I have to admit I didn't read your code. The problem is with Chrome, try your JSFiddle in that browser and the lists are vertically aligned to the bottom.

Comment: Cool it does not show up properly in chrome. By the way i told you that it works perfectly in Firefox. :)

Comment: "i told you that it works perfectly in Firefox" - fair point :)

Comment: I found that adding `vertical-align: top;` fixes the problem in Chrome, so your solution works in Firefox and Chrome. All I need to do now is get it working in IE (although I wish I didn't have to!)

Comment: @Tony Can you tell me from which version are you looking for. Coz it is working fine with IE 8+ versions. only IE7 has the issue with `display:inline-table` we need a fix here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10477/discussion-between-tony-and-murtaza)

Comment: The `inline-table` solution has come back to bite me... we have people with IE7 who access the site and they are reporting problems with the formatting. Is there any way you know of to solve the list layout in IE7, as it does not understand `display:inline-table` ?

Comment: ok we will need to apply some filter on it. let try something. I will update you soon

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use `:nth-child` for this may be that's help you. write like this:

```
#footer-menu > ul > li:nth-child(5){
    clear:both;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/PV8Bq/1/

But nth-child is not work in IE

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PV8Bq/10/)

I also cleaned a little bit your code, and reduce margin to allow 4 first blocks to fit in a row.

Comment: Looks good, although I'm slightly suspicious of the `margin-right: -70px;` attribute in the `#footer-menu ul li ul` block. If the top level item names change length I assume that will have to change. Your solution also does not render well in FireFox but I guess that's the problem with CSS solutions, there are always browser incompatibilities.